# Joining 2 date fields within a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I currently have problem with having 2 date fields that drives 2 different report that I have currently just joined.  One is called Month_start_dt and the other is Tran_dt.  Month_start_dt is driving a revenue report and Tran_dt is driving the performance report.  I have staged the 2 queries into a new table, but the 2 date doesn't match with same customer_id.  I would like to see how I can combine the 2 date so in the Tableau report, I can use one date filter for performance and revenue information.

Thanks

currently the data looks like this:

```
customer_id/month_start_dt/Tran_dt

11111 / 12-1-2017 / 4-20-2017

22222 / 11-1-2017 / 12-3-2017

33333 / 9-1-2016 / 4-6-2017

44444 / 2-1-2017 / 5-3-2016
```

Want result to look like this:

```
customer_id / month_start_dt

11111 / 12-1-2017

11111 / 4-20-2017

22222 / 11-1-2017

22222 / 12-3-2017

33333 / 9-1-2016

33333 / 4-6-2017

44444 / 2-1-2017

44444 / 5/3/2016
```

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> Postgres!!!

Comment: Yes. First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the rows of any table by using a `cross join` and a subquery that simply returns 2 rows can be used for this. e.g.:

```
select
    customer_id
  , case when rn = 1 then month_start_dt else Tran_dt end month_start_dt
  , case when rn = 1 then 'month_start_dt' else 'Tran_dt' end dt_type
from table1
cross join (select 1 as rn union all select 2) cj
```

would produce:

```
| customer_id |       month_start_dt |        dt_type |
|-------------|----------------------|----------------|
|       11111 | 2017-12-01T00:00:00Z | month_start_dt |
|       11111 | 2017-04-20T00:00:00Z |        Tran_dt |
|       22222 | 2017-11-01T00:00:00Z | month_start_dt |
|       22222 | 2017-12-03T00:00:00Z |        Tran_dt |
|       33333 | 2016-09-01T00:00:00Z | month_start_dt |
|       33333 | 2017-04-06T00:00:00Z |        Tran_dt |
|       44444 | 2017-02-01T00:00:00Z | month_start_dt |
|       44444 | 2016-05-03T00:00:00Z |        Tran_dt |
```

Note, the query above works in both MySQL & Postgres, but it really helps if we know exactly which db type to target. Please only tag with the correct db